# Validation on Field : JavaScript regex required for Field

Tags: javascript, regex

Following is the requirement of field value should be - else it should generate an error

> Format to be only 9 characters with 2 letters, followed by 6 numbers,
>   followed by one letter

**e.g. 'AB332211C'**

Any else value should generate an error message using JavaScript. Can anyone help me in creating regex expression for this.

**EDITS :** Till yet I am done with this : Help to improve the same

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var myAssumption = /^\d{2}[a-zA-z] \d{6}[0-9]\d{1}[a-zA-z]$/;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following links might help in answering : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/Mustbeatleast3charactersandnotmorethan8.htm

Examples :

```
// Common regexs
  var regexEmail = /^([\w]+)(.[\w]+)*@([\w]+)(.[\w]{2,3}){1,2}$/;
  var regexUrl = /^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([\w]+)(.[\w]+){1,2}$/;
  var regexDate = /^\d{1,2}(\-|\/|\.)\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$/;
  var regexTime = /^([1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d$/;
  var regexIP = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])$/;
  var regexInteger = /(^-?\d\d*$)/; **
```

Comment: How about this.. /^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z])$/ ?

Comment: yep, whqat's wrong with `/^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z])$/` ? Why you added a space `\d{6}` ?

Comment: 2 letters, followed by 6 numbers, and Last 1 is letter again. I guess we are not looking at proper length

Comment: i think the above regex would satisfy your condition.

Comment: @NileshMendhe What do you mean by `not looking at proper length`? As asked `9 characters with 2 letters, followed by 6 numbers, followed by one letter`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar : It worked- but need to handle Trims too - blanks spaces- put that in answers with it

Comment: @NileshMendhe blank spaces required at???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\b[A-z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-z]{1}$/.test('AB332211C')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help..

`/^[ ]*([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z])[ ]*$/`

`[a-zA-Z]{2}` matches two alphabetic character

`\d{6}` matches subsequent 6 digits

`[a-zA-Z]` matches one alphabetic character

Comment: should also handle blank space before and after

Comment: @NileshMendhe actual space added at start and end, but this will make compulsory to have spaces at both ends...Does that comply with requirement?

Comment: I mean, it should also match if I put any blank spaces before or after ---- Like we handle using .TRIM() usually. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

/^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z])$/

```
1st Capturing group ([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}[a-zA-Z])
[a-zA-Z]{2} match a single character present in the list below

Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)

\d{6} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {6} Exactly 6 times

[a-zA-Z] match a single character present in the list below
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
```

[Check this](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP7cI2/1), show with all explanation.